GPU crashes at 60 fps , works well at 40
I am using Alienware M14x
My cpu is i7 with a Nvidia geforce gt555

The issue gets resolved as soon as i switch to 40fps ,
but i want to use my laptop at 60 fps , everytime i switch to 60 fps half of my screen goes off.
Here is a google drive video link
I have tried many solutions from Youtube, also i tried setting the performance to max quality in Nvidia command center, all of my drivers are up to date, and still it does not work.

You have a 12 years old laptop. High standard for gaming in 2012, quite underpowered by today standards.

@ChanganAuto That i agree , but can you help me by providing any solutions?

@SuTech - Your hardware doesn’t seems to support 60 Hz refresh rate. Since there is a laptop your desire to run at a higher refresh rate won’t be possible

@Ramhound My laptop does support 60 hertz refresh Rate ND I am pretty sure about that , here are the screenshots .
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VcUUIuZ5X95z4POI12vQQUdUG7QvYjFL?usp=sharing
I was using 60fps since many years , i do not know what problem has occurred , i had to switch to 40fps , cuz it started acting like this

It could be a soft failure of the display. They are not designed to last forever.

Can i get any solution?

@ChanganAuto Also i do not want to do any high end gaming on this , i just want that half of the screen should not go off , i just want to watch youtube...

@SuTech - You could try and replace the display, it could be the cable or the display, both would be more expensive the. The entire laptop is worth. So I can’t really recommend you waste money like that. You are expecting way too much from your 12 year old hardware

I thought 60fps is nothing for it

Buy a new PC, reduce resolution, or play at 40 Hz.

Possible problem(s); examples: Oxide on internal connectors, this or other issues makes the hardware run hot and turn partly off due to the heat. Alternatively it might have been running in a hot state as long as you have used it (cooling fans ineffective due to dust accumulation?) and now has a heat sensitive state due to component internal degradation.

Here are the steps you must follow. These are the normal and standard steps for diagnosing any issue like this.
Install the latest versions of all drivers, firmware, and software that support your computer.
If the issue persists, use a "live" Linux distribution such as Ubuntu to run a different OS on your hardware without messing with the OS installed on the disk. See if this screen works at 60Hz in the live environment.
If the screen and run stably at 60Hz on an alternate OS, the problem is likely in your original OS, so perform a clean reinstall, installing all the updated drivers and software, and see if this resolves this.
Try a different screen. Does an external monitor run successfully at 60Hz? If so, the problem is likely limited to your internal display and/or its connectors. This means the GPU and other system internals are probably OK.
With a laptop, this is probably as far as you can go. To be frank, besides updating your OS, drivers, and firmware, this sort of issue is probably not fixable unless you are a competent and confident PC hardware technician. Laptops are not designed to be very serviceable, and all electronic devices do wear out eventually, especially consumer electronic goods. Simple use of these devices produces small amounts of wear over time, even when you care for them very well.

Yes it did not work on chrome os flex , it did crash on it as well , so there may be a problem in hardware . I will try ubuntu

Then you already have your answer: Your hardware is aged and failing.
